# Complexity of $\oplus$ 3-REGULAR BIPARTITE PLANAR VERTEX COVER

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, complexity-classes, counting-complexity

The $\oplus$3-REGULAR BIPARTITE PLANAR VERTEX COVER problem consists in computing the parity of the number of vertex covers of a 3-regular bipartite planar graph.

> **Question**
>
> 1. Which is the complexity of such problem? Is it $\oplus$P-hard, or is it in P?
> 2. What if we remove the planarity restriction (i.e. $\oplus$3-REGULAR BIPARTITE VERTEX COVER)?

The closest I was able to find is that $\oplus$3/2 BIPARTITE PLANAR VERTEX COVER is $\oplus$P-complete (see Theorem 2.2 in [this paper](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~valiant/focs06.pdf)).

Comment: Right now, I do not have the access to the paper by Xia and Zhao which Colin McQuillan and András Salamon cited in [this answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/trees-complexity-of-counting-the-number-of-vertex-covers/5567#5567) to one of your previous questions, but it seems very relevant.  Can you explain why it does not answer this question?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: I know that paper. However, such paper is about the #P-hardness of counting vertex covers on 3-regular bipartite planar graphs. Here I'm interested in computing just the parity of the number of vertex covers. It is not obvious that counting them being #P-hard implies computing their parity being $\oplus$P-hard. For instance, see http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hguo/Papers/ParityHP.pdf: in the very first lines of the introduction they say _"...including graph matchings and some coloring problems, for which the parity
problem is in P but exact counting is #P-complete [Val10]"_.

Comment: Of course #P-hardness of counting does not automatically imply ⊕P-hardness of deciding the parity.  What I am wondering is whether the proof of the #P-hardness of #3-regular bipartite planar vertex cover by Xia and Zhao also shows the ⊕P-hardness of ⊕3-regular bipartite planar vertex cover.  I cannot check whether it does or not because I (still) do not have access to the paper, but I assume that you have read their proof.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Your assumption is flawed (unfortunately for me). As I do not have access to their paper (neither now nor previously), I did not read it (although I would have liked to). I'm only aware of the title and the abstract.

Comment: Unfortunalety old subject.
This problem is very interesting and I'm also looking for answer on this question.
For general graphs (probably even for 5-regular graphs) problem parity vertex cover is as hard as breaking RSA, factorization and many other NP-hard problems. I don't know if this NP-hard problems can be transformed in poly time to ⊕ 3-REGULAR BIPARTITE PLANAR VERTEX COVER, but it is still an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, according to the paper [Accidental algorithms](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~valiant/focs06.pdf) by Valiant, the  problem ⊕Pl-3/2Bip-Mon-2CNF is ⊕P-complete. So ⊕ 3-REGULAR PLANAR VERTEX COVER would also have to be ⊕P-complete. So it's not in P (unless P = ⊕P-complete).
But I still don't know if ⊕ 3-REGULAR BIPARTITE PLANAR VERTEX COVER is ⊕P-complete.